# How to reverse the decimal digits of a number?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I want to reverse a number from an array in assembly.

I want to reverse a number if its greater than -50.
If it's 24 it becomes 42.
If it's -15 it becomes -51

Following is some part of my code

```
data segment
       arr1 db 12,34,56,42
ends

stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment
start:

mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

mov si,offset arr1 

push [si]

sort:
mov cx,-1



cmp [si],-50
jg reverse
inc si
jmp sort

reverse:
mov al,[si]
rol al,cl 
mov [si],al 
inc si
jmp sort


mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h  

ends

end start
```

Comment: Do you mean bit-reverse, so `0x80` becomes `0x01`?  What output do you want vs. what output you actually get?  (include this in your question along with your [mcve], see [ask].) 
 You're actually just rotating right by 1 (which you could do a lot more efficiently with `ror al,1` instead of by `cl` with `cl = 0xFF`).  Also, comment your code, especially if you want others to read it.  I have no idea why you'd `push [si]`; copying 2 bytes from the array to the stack makes no sense.

Comment: I assume this is EMU8086 (I added that tag) because most assemblers would reject `cmp [si], -50` as ambiguous between byte vs. word operand-size.  But EMU8086 has a default which might be byte, I forget.  You could check with a disassembler or its built-in debugger.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic describes the need to include the desired behaviour in your question, e.g. an example value that you'd like `12` to turn into.

Comment: I need to reverse any number in an array if its greater than -50 . If its 24 it becomes 42 and if its -15 it becomes -51.

Comment: [edit] this into your question like I told you.  Anyway, you need division by 10 to do stuff in terms of decimal digits, not binary rotates.

Comment: If i do that and get a remainder and my result then how i do merge both of them together since i want a reversed number?

Comment: I understand now, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For the routines to solve your problem, it is first to convert the number you wanted to reverse into single digits. Read those single digits in the reverse order and convert that back to the whole digit.

To convert any number to an array of single digits, you would have to divide the number by 10 until the quotient is 0. Each time you divide, the remainders are the digits that you would want to save and the quotient is the new number to be divide by 10 if it is not zero. For example if I want to convert 109 to an array of single digits I would do this:

```
109 / 10 = quotient(10) , remainder(9) = 9 is the single digit of this round
10 / 10  = q(1) , r(0)                 = 0 is the single digit of this round
1 / 10   = q(0) , r(1)                 = 1 is the single digit of this round
```

From the above example, if I read each digit from top to bottom, I would have got my number reverse. Where if I read from bottom to top then that is my original number.

This code handles negative numbers by saving the sign (to restore at the end) and working with the unsigned absolute value for the division and multiplication part.

Below is an example code that I wrote in assembly. From the example code, the revN is the routine that you want to look at, the printN is just a support routine.

The code was written in NASM assembly and for 32 bit mode on Linux, with `int 0x80` system calls made directly. You can use https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_assembly_online.php or https://www.jdoodle.com/compile-assembler-nasm-online/ to test it. Take note that The Code Will Not Check For Overflow.

Thank you to [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) for the feedbacks on the answer's code. With the feedback, I decided to optimize the answer code. Nonetheless, I decided to keep the first version of the code and post the optimized version of revN below the first code, as it is easier to understand the steps from the first code.

For the second version of revN, to negate negative and positive, because of performance, the "neg" instruction was use instead of "not" and "inc". Also, "xor r32, r32" was used instead of "mov r32, 0". Besides those, the second of revN does not convert the number to single digits chars and store them in an array. Instead, it convert the digits back to the number while parsing the number to single digits. This is because when parsing 109 to digits, the 9 first then 0 then 1. Thus, if convert that back to a number while parsing them would equal to (((9 * 10) + 0) * 10) + 1. The second example code, Answer 2, only contained the revN routine. To test it right away, replace the revN portion of Answer 1 with the revN of Answer 2.

## Answer 1

```
section .data
    sys_write equ 4                 ;EAX
    sys_exit equ 1

    stdout equ 1                    ;EBX

    cKernal equ 0x80                ;INT

                                    ;printN CONST
    min32 equ -2147483648           ;Minimum negative value for signed 32
    printN_chunk equ 12

section .text
    global _start                   ; Must be declared for using gcc

_start:                             ; Tell linker entry point
    ; Test 1 
    mov eax, 45                     ; N to be reverse
    mov edi, -15                    ; If N <= to this don't reverse
    call revN
                                    ; eax is N to print
    mov edx, dword 10               ; EndL
    call printN

    ; Test 2
    mov eax, 0                      ; N to be reverse
    mov edi, -15                    ; If N <= to this don't reverse
    call revN
                                    ; eax is N to print
    mov edx, dword 10               ; EndL
    call printN

    ; Test 3
    mov eax, -13                    ; N to be reverse
    mov edi, -15                    ; If N <= to this don't reverse
    call revN
                                    ; eax is N to print
    mov edx, dword 10               ; EndL
    call printN

    ; Test 4
    mov eax, -18                    ; N to be reverse
    mov edi, -15                    ; If N <= to this don't reverse
    call revN
                                    ; eax is N to print
    mov edx, dword 10               ; EndL
    call printN

    ; Test 5
    mov eax, -78945                 ; N to be reverse
    mov edi, -100000                ; If N <= to this don't reverse
    call revN
                                    ; eax is N to print
    mov edx, dword 10               ; EndL
    call printN

    ; Test 6
    mov eax, min32                  ; N to be reverse
    mov edi, min32                  ; If N <= to this don't reverse
    call revN
                                    ; eax is N to print
    mov edx, dword 10               ; EndL
    call printN

    ; Test 7
    mov eax, 987542478              ; N to be reverse
    mov edi, min32                  ; If N <= to this don't reverse
    call revN
                                    ; eax is N to print
    mov edx, dword 10               ; EndL
    call printN


    ; Exit
    mov eax, sys_exit               ;system call number (sys_exit)
    int cKernal                     ;call kernel

revN:
    ; WARNING THIS DOES NOT CHECK FOR OVERFLOW

                                    ; EAX ARG Number to be reversed
                                    ; EDI ARG Number to be compared to

                                    ; if EAX <= EDI return value = EAX

                                    ; EAX is also the return value

                                    ; Each digit is stored as word, so
                                    ; so that they are exactly the size of
                                    ; an extended register

    push ebp                        ; Save ebp
                                    ; EBP is used as pointer after len. 

    sub esp, 48                     ; Set stack pointer. 
                                    ; Reserve memory 
                                    ; 40 = 10(n) * 4 
                                    ;  4 = signbit
                                    ;  4 = len
                                    ; 48 byte

    lea ebp, [esp+8]                ; Set ebp to before signbit

    cmp eax, edi                    ; Compare eax(arg1) to edi(arg2)
    jle revN_exit                   ; If n <= edi return n

    cmp eax, 0                      ; Compare eax to zero
    jl revN_2Str_nNeg               ; If n is neg turn it to pos
    je revN_exit                    ; If n is 0 return n

    mov dword [esp+4], 0            ; If n not neg set sign bit to 0
                                    ; This is just to ensure
                                    ; accuracy, usually this doesn't have 
                                    ; to be set as we haven't touch
                                    ; the stack.

  revN_2Str:      
                                    ; revN_2Str(in reverse)
                                    ; Register Ultilization:
                                    ; edx (div)
                                    ; Save eax (div)
                                    ; Save ebx (counter)
                                    ; Save ecx (divider)

    ; First number is converted to string in reverse
    mov ebx, 0                      ; Counter (Position counter) 
                                    ;  to get digit divide to 4.
    mov ecx, 10                     ; Divider
    mov edx, 0                      ; EDX:EAX /

  revN_2Str_div:
    idiv ecx                        ; EDX:EAX / 10 = EDX(r) : EAX(q)
    mov [ebp + ebx],  edx           ; move the result to stack
                                    ; edx will always be leass than 10
    mov edx, 0                      ; reset edx
    add ebx, 4                      ; increase counter

    cmp eax, 0                      ; compare quotient to 0
    jne revN_2Str_div               ; reloop if quotient is not 0

                                    ; if Done copy the length 
    mov dword [esp], ebx            ; to the stack location of esp
    mov eax, dword [ebp]            ; Move the first digit into eax

    cmp dword [esp], 4              ; Compare len against 4
    jle revN_exit                   ; If one digit or 4 byte we are done

    mov ebx, 4                      ; Set the counter for revN_toNum

  revN_toNum:
                                    ; revN_toNum(Convert str2int32)
                                    ; This does not check for overflow
                                    ; Register Ultilization:
                                    ; eax (n to be return)
                                    ; edx = eax << 3
                                    ; Save ebx (counter)

    mov edx, eax                    ; Copy eax to edx
    shl eax, 1                      ; Shift eax x 1 left = eax * 2
    shl edx, 3                      ; shift edx x 3 left = edx * 8
    add eax, edx                    ; EAX + EDX = EAX * 10
    add eax, dword [ebp + ebx]      ; ADD another digit
    add ebx, 4                      ; increase counter
    cmp ebx, dword [esp]            ; check counter
    jl revN_toNum                   ; reloop if counter < len

    cmp dword [esp+4], 1            ; Check sign bit
    je revN_toNum_nNeg              ; If n is neg turn it to neg

  revN_exit:
    add esp, 48                     ; reset stack pointer
    pop ebp                         ; Restore ebp
ret

revN_2Str_nNeg:
                                    ; Turn n to negative
    not eax                         ; Bitwise not
    inc eax                         ; Add 1
    mov dword [esp+4], 1            ; Set sign bit
    jmp revN_2Str                   ; convert to str

revN_toNum_nNeg:
    not eax                         ; Turn n to positive
    inc eax                         ; Add 1
    jmp revN_exit                   ; Jump to exit


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;                                  ;
; Below is the printN function     ;
; Use where can't use printf       ;
; or similar function              ;
;                                  ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

printN:
                                    ; EAX ARG Number to print
                                    ; EDX ARG end of line < 255 or ending char


                                    ; before calling this



    push ebp                        ; Push ebp onto the stack
    mov ebp, esp                    ; Top of stack

    sub esp, printN_chunk           ; 12 = sign + 10 digits + endl

                                    ; edx (div)
                                    ; eax (div)
                                    ; ebx (counter)
                                    ; ecx (divider)
                                    ; esi (0/1)(pos/neg)

    dec ebp                         ; ebp decrement 1
    mov byte [ebp], dl              ; Add end line

    mov ebx, 1                      ; Counter start at 1 (endl)
    mov ecx, 10                     ; Divider

    cmp eax, 0                      ; Compare eax to 0
    jl printN_nNeg                  ; If n is neg
    je printN_n0                    ; If n is 0
    mov esi, 0                      ; Set positive flag

  printN_start:    
    mov edx, 0                      ; EDX:EAX / 

  printN_div:
    idiv ecx                        ; EDX:EAX / 10 = EDX(r) : EAX(q)
    or edx,  48                     ; or to get the ascii code

    dec ebp                         ; decrease ebp 
    mov byte [ebp], dl              ; push to stack
    inc ebx                         ; increase counter

    mov edx, 0                      ; reset edx

    cmp eax, 0                      ; compare quotient to 0
    jne printN_div                  ; reloop if quotient is not 0

    cmp esi, 0                      ; Check if n positive
    je printN_print                 ; If positive print

    dec ebp                         ; ebp decrease
    mov byte [ebp], '-'             ; Else, add a neg sign
    inc ebx                         ; increase counter

  printN_print:

    mov edx, ebx                    ; strlen = message length
    mov ecx, ebp                    ; Message to write
    mov ebx, stdout                 ; File descriptor (stdout)
    mov eax, sys_write              ; System call number (sys_write)
    int cKernal                     ; Call kernel

  printN_exit:
    add esp, printN_chunk           ; Reset esp
    pop ebp                         ; Restored ebp
ret

printN_nNeg:
    cmp eax, min32                  ; Compare arg vs minimum neg value.
    je printN_nMin                  ; If it is just print the neg value.

    not eax                         ; Bitwise not
    inc eax                         ; Add 1
    mov esi, 1                      ; Set neg flag
    jmp printN_start                ; Start

printN_n0:
    dec ebp                         ; ebp decrease
    mov byte [ebp], '0'             ; push a 0
    inc ebx                         ; increase counter
    jmp printN_print                ; jump to print

printN_nMin:
    add ebx, 11                     ; Add 11 chars to counter
                                    ; Then push min number on to the stack
                                    ; backward
    sub ebp, 4
    mov dword [ebp], dword "3648"                
    sub ebp, 4
    mov dword [ebp], dword "4748"
    sub ebp, 2
    mov word [ebp], word "21"
    sub ebp, 1
    mov byte [ebp], byte "-"
    jmp printN_print                ; Jump to print
```

## Answer 2

```
revN:
    ; INFO
    ; @DESCRIPTION - Reverse a number 
    ;
    ; @NOTE - This routine can probably be optimized futher using
    ; a high performance base 10 division algorithm.
    ;
    ; @WARNING - THIS DOES NOT CHECK FOR OVERFLOW

    ; REG SAVE AND RESTORE
    ; edi
    ; esi

    ; ARGS
    ; eax - number to be reversed
    ; edi - Number to be compared to

    ; RETURNS
    ; eax - the reversed input number or the input number
    ;       itself if "input eax <= input edi".

    ; REGISTER UTILIZATION
    ; edx (div)
    ; eax (div)
    ; ebx (negative flag)
    ; ecx (divider)
    ; edi (temporary answer)
    ; esi (temporary variable)

    ; END INFO
    push edi                        ; SAVE edi
    push esi                        ; SAVE esi

    cmp eax, edi                    ; Compare eax(arg1) to edi(arg2)
    jle revN_exit                   ; If n <= edi return n

    cmp eax, 0                      ; Compare eax to zero
    jl revN_start_nNeg              ; If n is neg turn it to positive
    je revN_exit                    ; If n is 0 return n

    xor ebx, ebx                    ; Set negative flag = 0

  revN_start:
    mov ecx, 10                     ; Divider
    xor edx, edx                    ; edx = 0

    ; This below stay outside of loop is to save calculation 
    ; on the first digit and also on one digit input
    idiv ecx                        ; EDX:EAX / 10 = EDX(r) : EAX(q)

    mov edi, edx                    ; Move first digit into edi

    cmp eax, 0                      ; Compare quotient to 0
    je revN_fin                     ; Finish if quotient is 0 

  revN_loop:    
    xor edx, edx                    ; Reset edx to 0
    idiv ecx                        ; EDX:EAX / 10 = EDX(r) : EAX(q)

    mov esi, edi                    ; Copy edi to esi
    shl edi, 3                      ; Shift edi x 3 left = eax * 8
    shl esi, 1                      ; shift esi x 1 left = esi * 2
    add edi, esi                    ; EDI + ESI = EDI * 10    

    add edi, edx                    ; Add another digit 

    cmp eax, 0                      ; Compare quotient to 0
    jne revN_loop                   ; Reloop if quotient is not zero 

  revN_fin:    
    mov eax, edi                    ; Move temprary answer to 
                                    ;  return register.

    cmp ebx, 1                      ; Check negative flag
    je revN_fin_nNeg                ; If n was negative turn it 
                                    ;  to negative.
  revN_exit:
    pop esi                         ; RESTORE esi
    pop edi                         ; RESTORE edi
ret

revN_start_nNeg:
    neg eax                         ; Turn n to positive
    mov ebx, 1                      ; Set sign bit
    jmp revN_start                  ; Jump to start

revN_fin_nNeg:
    neg eax                         ; Turn n to negative
    jmp revN_exit                   ; Jump to exit
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203575/discussion-on-answer-by-kevin-ng-how-to-reverse-a-number-in-assembly-language-8).

Comment: What's the point of the `edi` arg?  The conditional skip should just be left to the caller if desired, instead of *forcing* the caller to set EDI to something.  Consider standard C functions like `sin()` or `sqrt()` - they don't take a 2nd arg to maybe return their primary arg unchanged.

Comment: @PeterCordes - That is true, but it seemed the questioner wanted to skip on some values. So I thought this would be easy for the questioner. Plus, this can't flip int_min value. So if you want all number you can just set edi int_min.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about that in the question.  Still, the calling loop should include that, not the reverse function.  I think being impossible to make it *try* to flip INT_MIN is a bad design.  It does work correctly, returning the low 32 bits of the correct result.

Comment: @PeterCordes, it is not possible to flip INT_MIN either. That is because INT_MIN flipped is overflow quite a few times.

Comment: @PeterCordes - It is possible to flip INT_MIN, but only in string format. But that would be a string reverser or byte array reverser, and it is pretty easy to convert this into a string reverser.

Comment: I meant you can run this and get `0x783f00c`, which is the low 32 bits of the `0xfffffffe0783f00c` full result.  We already talked about this in chat yesterday.  It accepts lots of other inputs that overflow, so why should INT_MIN be special?  i.e. passing INT_MIN in EDI should "turn off that feature" entirely, IMO, if you insist on keeping it part of that function instead of leaving it to the caller.  If you designed it as `if(eax < edi) return;` that would let you run it for `INT_MIN` if you wanted to (so the OP would pass `-49` as the lowest number to reverse).

Comment: @PeterCordes - But what the point of giving back part of the overflow? That would not be accurate. If the OP want to reverse an unlimited amount of number. He could do it in string. Or he could use a really large array and calculate his own constant for division of quotient and remainder. That, he could calculate number maybe up to a few megabyte in length. But does he have the time to do that?

Comment: It's not a matter of that result being truly useful for anything (and I know how digit-strings and base 10 vs. binary extended precision work, thanks), it's more a matter of good engineering practice to create fewer corner cases for someone debugging a caller that passes values that overflow.  Make it possible to fully disable an optional feature.  (Or leave it to the caller to not call in the first place would be my real recommendation.  For callers that already did input validation, this extra check is pure downside: you have to pass an extra arg.)

Comment: @PeterCordes - Thank you for your comment those. It actually not an extra check. It make it easy for the OP to use the code since the OP wanted to omit a certain range. For him to implement a check, he can just check the overflow flag after each mul. It not hard to implement. But I think the example is pretty simple and straight forward. For engineer practice. Lot of function we use daily require us to implement a check on our code. For example, if you going to parse a number. The library for some reason think that checking is our responsibility.

Comment: @PeterCordes - But the problem here is checking a string of digits, you would have to go through it one by one. Parsing it also does the same thing. So why not save computational power and check it while you are there? Why not split the function up and run a check if ask to and not if not being asked for? Is that good engineering practice?

Comment: @PeterCordes - Although a big thank to you for pointing out neg is faster than inc and not, I think the code above is pretty efficient. It pretty easy to customize to the necessary usage case. I am pretty sure you can customize it within a few minutes.

Comment: Yes obviously I could remove the check that I don't like.  But SO answers should be example of good design of APIs when possible, making good choices of how to divide responsibility for different parts of a problem into separate functions.  This is what I'm talking about.  (Although really this problem wants to *print* the decimal-reversed number, so just dumping it into a `char` buffer in LSD-first order would be more efficient than mul+add back into a binary integer that a print function has to break apart again.)  No idea why you're still talking about strings of digits; I didn't say that.

Comment: @PeterCordes - I think the OP wanted to reverse the numbers in array. It is possible that the OP will store them in the same array. If it is that case it would pretty easy for the OP to use my function. The OP can just call this function on all the OP's array index without checking if the OP's numbers are <= something. So for the OP's usage case, if the OP does not need to check for overflow, this code best fit for the OP.